# missing wordpress rss feed?

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed

I have a site created with wordpress and I would like to inform all my visitors about the latest uploads and/or posts.
I tried to use WP RSS Aggregator, but I can't even get my feed using: https://dir.szkt.hu/feed/ as suggested in wp codex.
I do not get a basic feed list, just a bunch of crapy code:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9J4y.jpg)

Ps help me.
Thx

Comment: Your feed url is not loading, going to admin login page. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

The URL that you included in your question is going to a login page.

The most likely situation is that you, in your browser, logged into your site, are seeing the raw XML code of the feed. But when you put the URL into a feed reader, that software is **not** authenticated to the site. It sees the HTML of your login page, just like any random visitor to the site would.

Since the login page's HTML is not a valid feed, you get an error:

> Invalid feed URL

The probable solution: you need to make the feed URL public, and not require a login to view it.

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for the answer.
I'm using "Members" and "Simple LDAP Login" plugins, to ensure that only our registered coworkers can read the site.
I turned off these plugins for a minute, and I could reach the feed.
I tried "Feedburner" to make a public feed, but no success yet.
How can I make my feed public and still use my plugins?
Thx for help!

Comment: @AttilaMucsi I'm not familiar with the Members plugin, but that is probably the one to look at. It may have settings to exclude certain items or URLs from the login restriction. However, if you are intentionally restricting your content to be readable only by members, are you sure you want a public feed? That feed will basically create a login bypass and defeat the login protection that Members provides.

Comment: So basicaly there is no way to generate a private feed, that can be used to notify memebers only and can be used/seen by members only.
If it's true, I have to make my own plugin to do this function... :(

Answer (score 0):

It is the feed. Use some feed reader to view it correctly.

Comment: I tried WP RSS Aggregator and got this:
Invalid feed URL - Double check the feed source URL setting above.

I tried Feedzy RSS Feeds Lite, and got nothing.

Is that possible, that my WP page does not generate any rss feed at all?